# Get values from text file and pass it to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, rhq

I am new to java script and writing rhq cli scripts for automation where `js` is used to call rhq API .

what i need is , want to get the values from the text file and pass it to an array using java script Please assist on this.
[image]

Above is the cli commands used in rhq ... where i must pass the values into the the array "mstarray" from file.

Please help on this.

Comment: Where is `text` ? Where is your code ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @dandavis, How about `ajax` ?

Comment: if text file is on server then use  ajax, if it's on the client, then FileReader...

Comment: var crit = new MeasurementDefinitionCriteria();
crit.fetchResourceType(true);
crit.addFilterPluginName('JBossAS7');
crit.addFilterResourceTypeName('Memory');
crit.addFilterDefaultOn(false);
crit.addFilterDisplayName('committed heap');
MeasurementDefinitionManager.findMeasurementDefinitionsByCriteria(crit);
var mstArray = [10022, 10025, 10026, 10029];
MeasurementScheduleManager.enableSchedulesForResourceType(mstArray, true)

Above is the cli commands used in rhq ... where i must pass the values into the the array "mstarray" from file.

Comment: btw. you can use also the python if you don't like javascript https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/Script+Modularity+-+Python